# WYSIWYG edit view of text is below image in content but node view isnt.

Tags: wysiwyg

In my WYSIWYG edit view ive hit return to make some text apear below an image in the content. However when I save the text is alongside the image, half way down but below.

Why does the edit and node view look different? How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible that the text format with which your field is being displayed is restrictive i.e. it only allows a subset of HTML tags.

I'm going to assume that you are talking about the *Body* field or more generally a text field attached to a Content type.

1. Ensure the `field_ui` module is enabled and go to the *Manage display* page for your content type. For the field in question, check if the formatter says *Default*.
2. Now, go to *Administration > Configuration > Content Authoring > Text formats* and inspect the first text format in the list.

If you are going to view as a different user, remember that Text formats are linked to permissions and an user's default text format is the first from the list in 2. *that he has access to* use.